# Quintessential vs essential?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, adjectives, ambiguity

While quintessential means 'representing the most perfect or typical example of a quality or class' [OED], it defines essential as 'absolutely necessary; extremely important'. I have noticed frequent instances of the two being used interchangeably. How did this come about?

Comment: *Essential* has more than one sense; if you read all the OED definitions it may be clearer.

Comment: Where do you see these being used interchangeably? They have quite different menaings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different borrowings, and different metaphors.

[*Essence*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/essentia) is from Latin *essentia* 'essence, being'.
It's a present active participle of the Latin verb *sum, esse, fūī, futūrus* 'to be'.
Just for comparison, *being* is the present active participle of the English verb *be, was, been*.

*Quintessence* comes from Mediaeval alchemical Latin, for *quinta essentia* '[fifth](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/penkwe.pdf) essence', meaning a potion that had been distilled five times. So it probably means *being* that's a hundred proof or more; i.e, it's an intensifier, like *very*. But since essence is so immaterial, there's no real difference between the meanings. *Quintessence* is a learned word, but that may or may not matter.

Comment: OED shares the common view of the etymology; "a fifth essence existing in addition to the four elements, supposed to be the substance of which the celestial bodies were composed" and hence more vital and real than the sublunary elements. But I don't suppose it matters.

Comment: @TimLymington Why is 'proof' singular in `a hundred proof or more`? Ought it NOT to be `a hundred proofS` ?

Comment: Like "percent", it is often used as a mass noun.

Comment: @LawArea51Proposal-Commit: No, *proof* is not the unit but the description of the scale. It would be incorrect to say "It's a hundred Fahrenheits out there".

Comment: @TimLymington Thanks. By 'scale', do you mean that for alcohol: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcohol_proof?

Answer (score 6):

I don't think they are even near to one another and even if someone comes across their cross reference it's should be considered a mistake.

All one can correlate between the two words is :-

- essential > essence of something (necessary for supporting the basics/a survival support )
- quintessential > essence of a thing in the purest form (for comfort/luxury/showoff etc.)

---

**Note:** *Though quintessential has it roots in **medival latin** which points towards **aether** [the classic element also known as fifth element(after earth, fire, water, and air)] but to the end that too points towards achieving the purest essence, of one which heavenly bodies are composed.*[[reference link]](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=quintessence&allowed_in_frame=0)

Also through the course of language and literature its meaning has kept on evolving following to current definitions along with their usage examples.

> [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus/british/quintessence): a feature of something that contains all of its main
>   qualities a, person or thing that is a perfect example of something
>   [Oxford](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/quintessential?q=quintessential): representing the most perfect or typical example of a
>   quality or class [Oxford advance learning dictionary](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/quintessential#quintessence__6): the perfect
>   example of something the most important features of something
>   [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/quintessentially): in such a way as to be most typically representative of
>   a quality, state, etc; perfectly [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/quintessential?q=quintessential): being the
>   most typical example or most important part of something [Merriam
>   webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/quintessential): constituting, serving as, or worthy of being a pattern to
>   be imitated

To further narrow down the ambiguity here is a [brief article on etymology](http://voices.yahoo.com/word-history-quintessential-752537.html?cat=4) of the same.

Comment: Exactly. An essential chocolate cake is one you can't get by without, even if other chocolate cakes are actually better. A quintessential chocolate cake is a perfect example of a chocolate cake, but not necessarily important or needed.

Comment: Since *quintessence* is merely 'the fifth essence', the connection is obvious. 'The essential difference' between two definitions does not mean it is necessary, but that it is a difference in their very substance, and could easily be replaced by *the quintessential difference*.

Comment: @Timlymington, ??. Sorry, Is it that both are replacable? Isn't using them otherwise a mistake?

Comment: Don't entirely follow your comment, but no, using *essential* to mean 'of the very essence' is no more wrong than meaning 'necessary'; the senses are distinct but related. (probably would have been less confusing if I had said *things* rather than *definitions*; apologies for mistimed attempt at cleverness.)

Comment: @Kate: Well-stated. That was a quintessential explanation.

Comment: @Timlymington, hope i have covered up the fifth element.

Comment: @KateGregory, that was a yum example. I'll be sure to call whoever exchanges the two a doosh.

Answer (score 2):

I researched this question in hopes to find an easy answer, but I came away more puzzled than when I started.

Here are the synonyms of *essential* suggested by my computer's on-board thesaurus (sure enough, there is *quintessential*, listed among the candidates), followed by the definitions provided by its dictionary:

[image: thesaurus/dictionary screen shots]
There are two oddities, at least in my mind. First, I can't find anything in the meaning of *essential* that carries the essence of *quintessential*; second, when I looked up the **other** synonyms for *essential* in the thesaurus (i.e., when I looked up *basic, inherent, fundamental, intrinsic, underlying,* etc.), they all listed *essential* as a synonym in the reverse direction. As can be seen by the bottom part of my screenshot, though, *essential* is conspicuously missing from the listed synonyms of *quintessential*.

This leads me to believe that using quintessential in place of *essential* would be a mistake, as Raghav said in an answer, and Kate Gregory mentioned in a comment. Yet it's not too often that such a "mistake" would be supported by a thesaurus.

I even looked up *essential* and *essentially* in the OED, as Tim Lymington suggested, and still couldn't find any clear-cut link.

Since I was unable to find a satisfactory answer to your question, I feel compelled to upvote it; it is a quintessential etymological puzzler.

Comment: The second sense given here for 'essential' largely overlaps with the meaning of 'quintessential'; the first sense (imperative / crucial) does not. Any overlap makes the words synonyms.

Answer (score 1):

Ritika, 
Have a look at this: [image: NGram]
suggesting that we don't see the words crossing each other, hence I would suggest they have not yet been replaced as yet. Besides in short, essential means *indispensable*, while quintessential means *the most typical*. And [Thesaurus.com](http://thesaurus.com/browse/quintessential) does point out *quintessential* as a synonym of essential, supporting what you mentioned in your original post, but I guess its like saying *I always procrastinate my work* then saying *I always delay my work until the end*.
See an example [here.](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/grammarlogs3/grammarlogs434.htm)
And both words have a different (and interesting) origin.

1. [quintessential](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/quintessential): derived from quintessence meaning the pure and concentrated essence of a substance. It has its story that Aristotle proposed this when he wanted to name the fifth element as quint + essence.
2. [essential](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/essence): having its origin from essence meaning: the basic, real, and invariable nature of a thing or its significant individual feature or features: Freedom is the very essence of our democracy.

Comment: How does this Ngram show that the words aren't interchangable? _Interchangable_ implies synonymous; the Ngram only tracks frequency. All this shows is that one word is less common than the other, but that can be said for [interchangable words](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+is+learned%2Che+is+erudite&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), too.

Comment: yup. just realized what i wrote! updated it thanks

Comment: "Been replaced?" Essentially, your Ngram shows that _essential_ (along with its adverbial form) are more common words than _quintessential_ and _quintessentially_, and also that the word _essentially_ grew in usage from around 1700 until its peak in the latter half of the 20th century. Nothing more.